# Woocommerce product categories into separate table in mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

How to get all woocommerce product categories into separate mysql table?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Note: It sounds like you're trying to get several pieces of data from different rows in the same table.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.post_title, p.guid, p.post_type, m.meta_key, m.meta_value, meta_sp.meta_value as sale_price, meta_ap.meta_value as additional_price
        FROM wp_posts p
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta_sp ON p.id=meta_sp.post_id 
            AND meta_sp.meta_key='sale_price'
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta_ap ON p.id=meta_ap.post_id 
            AND meta_ap.meta_key='additional_price'
        WHERE p.id=m.post_id
        AND m.meta_key='_rentable' AND m.meta_value='yes'
        ";
```

Comment: No, not like this way. I want like that Array
(
    [first_categoryid] => 88
    [first_category_name] => Business cards
)
Array
(
    [second_categoryid] => 98
    [second_category_name] => Signature
    [parent_categoryid] => 88
)
Array
(
    [second_categoryid] => 99
    [second_category_name] => Standard
    [parent_categoryid] => 88
)
Array
(
    [second_categoryid] => 101
    [second_category_name] => Ultra thick
    [parent_categoryid] => 88
)

Comment: Hi User42! It is not working, Its give me error  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Answer (score 0):

Well i am using the code way bcoz i not found any particular solution with mysql query, because its 3 level depth category. Its working and tested code.

```
    $all_categories = get_categories(array("taxonomy" => "product_cat", "parent" => 0, "show_count" => true)); 
        foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
                $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
                $sub = get_categories(array("taxonomy" => "product_cat", "parent" => $category_id));
                $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO product_category(cat_id, cat_name, parent_id)
                VALUES ( %d, %s, %d )", array($category_id, $cat->name, $cat->category_parent)));
                if(!empty($sub)){
                    foreach($sub as $subcat){
                        if($subcat->category_parent != ''){
                            $subcatid = $subcat->term_id; 
                            $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO product_category(cat_id, cat_name, parent_id)
                            VALUES ( %d, %s, %d )", array($subcatid, $subcat->name, $subcat->category_parent)));
                        }
                            $thirdlevel = get_categories(array("taxonomy" => "product_cat", "parent" => $subcatid));
                            if(!empty($thirdlevel)){
                                foreach($thirdlevel as $thirdcat){
                                    if($thirdcat->category_parent != ''){
                                        $lastcatid = $thirdcat->term_id;
                                        $thirdarray = array('cat_id'=> $lastcatid, 'cat_name'=>$thirdcat->name, 'parent_id'=> $thirdcat->category_parent);
                                    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO product_category(cat_id, cat_name, parent_id)
                                    VALUES ( %d, %s, %d )", array($lastcatid, $thirdcat->name, $thirdcat->category_parent)));
                                    }
                                }
                            }    
                    }
                }
        }
```

after these code you can use this query to fetch all the data from new table.

SELECT t1.cat_id AS lev1, t1.cat_name AS lev1name, t2.cat_id AS cat2, t2.cat_name AS cat2name, t3.cat_id AS lev3, t3.cat_name AS lev4
FROM product_category AS t1
LEFT JOIN product_category AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.cat_id
LEFT JOIN product_category AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.cat_id